# Excel code question

Tags: excel

I have 2 different excel files(all people and special people) that i want to kick special people from all people. Cant find a way.. if you don't understand check my example:

```
all people       special people
----------       --------------
1-john           1-john
2-jim            2-marry
3-mariah
4-russel
5-marry
```

I want:

```
all people     special people
----------     --------------
1-jim          1-john
2-mariah       2-marry
3-russel
```

Comment: Then it wouldn't be 'all people' ;)

Comment: yea because special people are not from all people :D they r special :D

Comment: You can use ADO. I can dig up an example, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

use =COUNTIF() in normal people to identify those who are special.
The sort on that column and delete the rows where the COUNTIF is not 0.

Comment: This is waht I had understood. So count in AllPeople those who are present in SpecialPeople. You then delet AllPeople having that count <> 0.